# Toolbar is not visible in android 4.4 tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have following layout in this I am adding a toolbar. Everything looks fine in Android 6.0 phones. I just tried it on android 4.2 tablet and the toolbar is not seen. here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.android.sushil.omdbclient.ui.main.MoviesList.MoviesListActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/windowBackground"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:visibility="visible">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/search_to_begin"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <!--<include layout="@layout/error_layout"/>-->
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I change the coordinator layout with Linearlayout, I can see the toolbar. But can someone tell me how can I fix this without replacing the coordinator layout with Linerlayout.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AppBarLayout` is obscured by your `RelativeLayout`.

From the `CoordinatorLayout` docs:

> CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout.

`FrameLayout` will draw children in definition order. So your `AppBarLayout` is drawn first, and your `RelativeLayout` is drawn second. Because your `RelativeLayout` has width and height of `match_parent` it fills the whole screen.

So the question is why this only happens on certain API levels, since it seems like my description should apply on any API level.

Turns out that `CoordinatorLayout` is a little bit smarter than `FrameLayout`, and on newer API levels it can do some special things to make sure your `AppBarLayout` is visible. On older API levels it can't do this by default.

However, you can fix this by adding an `app:layout_behavior` attr to your `<RelativeLayout>` tag. Just change this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

to this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

This attr will trigger the smart behavior to make sure your `AppBarLayout` is always visible, even on older API levels.

Answer (score 0):

You cold try declaring the android theme for your activities in android manifest.

For example:

```
  <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            </activity>
```

Comment: I am adding toolbar from my layout file.So, I have set the theme as NoActionBar

Comment: @Sushil Yes. You could try declaring it only in your manifest and not in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add these properties in your toolbar style.

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have them but still getting the issue